# Add a custom template Wordpress 3.5.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would think this is a relatively simple procedure but (being a total noob) I can't seem to figure it out. Is there a place from the admin dashboard to add and edit templates or do I have to use a FTP client to upload/edit templates directly? Thanks.

Comment: You can upload them in the templates folder, and they will show up in the admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your theme with the WordPress editor which can be found under:

```
Dashboard > Appearance > Editor
```

You have to make sure the files are writeable before you'll see a save button, you can make the files writeable via FTP.